# using angular ui-router for login page without including main project template

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

I used ui-router in my project. "index.html" has my root view that my project template apply in this view. 

now I want to load login page in my routing. but I didn't want to show login page with the project template(I want to have a login page without my project template, but will using my routing).

how do I that?

Comment: Not at all clear what you are asking or exactly what you are trying to do. What do you mean by *"main project template"*?

Comment: Why don't you just create another template to hold the login details, have a separate state for the login and assign it the new template?